# Is there a simple way to mute on Audio session?

Tags: avaudiosession, mute

Currently, I am working on an project for VoIP application on iOS,

what is best way to implement the mute function?

I have been searching for a while regarding this feature on AudioSesssion.

but I can not see which property or parameter to achieve my method.
like:

```
    AVAudioSession *session = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMute:true];
```

Thanks,